# Hibernate : String Index Out Of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, spring-data

I have a column in a MySql table that is defined as char(1).That column is having an empty value (not null). When reading this in using Hibernate, it throws an exception:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
>       at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)

This is my domain class of that table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ACTIONS",schema="IPLAN")
public class Actions
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="ID")
private long id;

@Column(name="TOTAL_HOURS")
private int hours;

@Column(name="TYPE")
private char type;
//getters and setters
}
```

***Update***:

I 'am facing this problem after updating the table.The query used is:

```
update actions set type=''
```

Please help!

Comment: I don't have much experience with hibernate, but i'd think it has something to do with using primitives. Try making it `Character`, it seems to me to be best practice to use wrappers anyway

Comment: I tried changing to Character.But still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems its value is not blank.

Check if you have 'SPACE' instead of blank.

Answer (score 0):

This issue due to `character field` in table for which you are using `char` as a data type so try changing char datatype to `TinyInt(1)`.

[This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) might help you in deep understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue was able to fix it by using String with length = 1